# Installing wine and steam (linux version) simultaneously on the same machine with Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, wine, steam, dbus

I am trying to setup new linux machine, primary for work and then light gaming when off-duty. Due to work part, I require wine to run some windows-specific software. However installing both steam and wine results in steam failing to launch.

I have been able to identify the culprit as libdbus-1-3:i386 package, that wine installs as one of its 32-bit dependencies. As soon as the package is installed, Steam crashes at launch.

I think that the reason for this is:

- that the steam uses its own local 32bit library for dbus, but prioritize using global version if present on a system, or
- that the steam does not have local 32bit library for dbus, but prioritize usage of 32bit dbus over 64bit, if both installed globally, or
- that the installation of 32bit dbus library somehow affects the working of the dbus-daemon.

So far, I have tried following:

- installing wine-stable from ubuntu repo;
- installing wine-develop from ubuntu repo;
- installing wine from wine ppa;
- installing wine-staging from ppa;
- reinstalling steam after installation of wine;
- removing only libdbus-1-3:i386, which I aborted because apt wanted to remove wine32 and libwine packages with it.

Thus, feeling that I've tried all noobish solutions I knew, I came here asking for help and/or inspiration.

Comment: Does the workaround in https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=882607#10 help?

Comment: Yes it does. It was enough to "export DBUS_FATAL_WARNINGS=0". Thank you good sir/madam. :) BTW. I did not know that steam for linux have a github. That may be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the Debian bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=882607#10) about this behaviour:

> This is a bug in Steam, which I think is specifically in the bundled copy of SDL 2.0.6 that it uses. It will crash in this way on everything that isn't a Debian derivative. On Debian derivatives, until recently a Debian-specific patch downgraded the response to failing the precondition check to a warning (this was done "temporarily" 11 years ago). "export DBUS_FATAL_WARNINGS=0" before running Steam would do the same thing as that patch. This will avoid the crash and just spam warnings instead, unless you are unlucky with the contents of uninitialized memory, in which case it might still crash.

So, the simplest workaround until this is fixed on the Steam side would be to run:

```
export DBUS_FATAL_WARNINGS=0
```

before running Steam from the command line. Alternatively, you can set this variable [permanently for your session](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Persistent_environment_variables).